# Different behavior between built and pulled docker image--clock errors?

Tags: docker, celery, docker-compose

I use docker and docker-compose to deploy an application. I've always built the images on the server (with `docker-compose build`) but recently transitioned to building them on my local machine and pushing them to Docker Hub, then pulling them onto the remote machine.

Since making this change, I've seen a strange new error in one of my containers. The compose file defines a Flask app and a celery worker that use the same codebase and Dockerfile (with different entrypoints). Since making the change, I get the following error every time I start my celery worker:

```
 app_worker_1: [2017-07-28 16:47:35,400: WARNING/MainProcess] Substantial drift from celery@worker.fb71685cd5a7 may mean clocks are out of sync.  Current drift is 48 seconds.  [orig: 2017-07-28 16:47:27.338937 recv: 2017-07-28 16:46:39.150362]
```

I've never seen this error before, and it goes away if the container is built on the server.

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    restart: always
    image: me/flask
    command: /home/app/start_app.sh
    env_file: ./flask/dev.env

  worker:
    restart: always
    image: me/flask
    command: /home/app/start_worker.sh
    env_file: ./flask/dev.env
```

Before, it looked like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    restart: always
    build: ./flask
    command: /home/app/start_app.sh
    env_file: ./flask/dev.env

  worker:
    restart: always
    build: ./flask
    command: /home/app/start_worker.sh
    env_file: ./flask/dev.env
```

Server is running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm building the images on my laptop, running Max OS X. The docker daemon on the server is 17.06.0-ce.

Comment: have you seen this one: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1802

Comment: @gesellix I had seen that and dismissed it as an old version, but missed the guy at the bottom complaining that it had happened on v 4+.